# Flex Communication Failure in AWS

Tags: java, apache-flex, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using java + blazeds + flex. Everything works fine on my computer,

acessing localhost:8080/project.

-- Problem --

1 - I upload my project to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

2 - I run my flex application

3 - I try to log in on my application ( Information is sent to back-end, Java )

4 - I receive this error, Fault Code: Client.Error.MessageSend

-- What I know --

- My message broker looks good when I type xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/messagebroker/amf

(white screen)

- Put a crossdomain file on my project root, but I receive the same error

This is my crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

-

It seems that AWS is blocking access from flex to java, any help? Thanks

Comment: Yes. This Error seems like something to do with crossdomain.xml not being referred.

Comment: I put the crossdomain, but it's not working.

Comment: Give us more information.  Your application works fine in what setting?  From your file system?  Or from a development web server? When you run it on AWS you get that error.  Are those the full error details?  What is the app doing when you see the error?  What code is executing? Where do you see the error? When do you see the error?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com added more information.

Comment: You need to put the cross domain file in the root of the server you are accessing.  I'm unclear if that is the same as your project root.  Based on info you provided, crossdomain should be accessible at xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/crossdomain.xml .  Are you sure your Flex code isn't accessing localhost?

Comment: Yes, it is, I can access xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/crossdomain.xml. Yes, everything I tried failed, but I figured out what was wrong. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. When you're running your project locally, you need to

provide a context root. On Flash Builder this information is under Project > Properties >

Flex  Server, and fields "Root URL" and "Context Root". But when you're running your

application on a  server host, let's say www.yoursite.com, you don't need the context root.

So your "Root URL" should be "http://localhost:8080/" and "Context Root" empty. After

changing your context root, delete all your files on your java projet and compile your flex

files on Flash Builder again.